# org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, cdi, glassfish-4

I have run into this "WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Injector] with qualifiers..." error when deploying a Maven project to Glassfish 4. I searched on the internet and added scope, added bean-discovery-mode="all", all other things and still could not get it work. I am learning Spring Framework and Java EE. Would someone please take a look at my code and help me out? Thanks!

stacktrace:

```
2014-01-28T11:29:44.755-0600|SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
2014-01-28T11:29:44.755-0600|SEVERE: Undeployment failed for context /MessageBoard
2014-01-28T11:29:44.786-0600|SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:Exception List with 2 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type   [Injector] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Inject org.eclipse.sisu.inject.DefaultBeanLocator.autoPublish(Injector)]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:325)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:177)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:208)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:519)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:505)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:480)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:536)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:216)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
```

codes:

```
package com.aaa.chapter5;

    public class MessageBoardServiceImpl implements MessageBoardService {

private Map<Long, Message> messages = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Message>();

public List<Message> listMessages() {

    return (List)messages.values();
}

public synchronized void postMessages(Message message) {
    Long id = System.currentTimeMillis();
    message.setId(id);
    messages.put(id, message);


}
}



package com.aaa.chapter5.web;


// Bind controller to URL /reservationForm
// initial view will be resolved to the name returned in the default GET method
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/messagePost*")
@RequestScoped
//@SessionAttributes("message") // Command name class was used in earlier Spring versions
public class MessagePostController {

    private MessageBoardService messageBoardService;


    @Autowired
    public void MessagePostController(MessageBoardService messageBoardService) {
       this.messageBoardService = messageBoardService;
}


// Controller will always look for a default GET method to call first, irrespective of name
// In this case, named setupForm to ease identification
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(Model model) {
// Create inital message object
    Message message = new Message();
// Add message to model so it can be display in view
    model.addAttribute("message", message);
    return "messagePost";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message, BindingResult result) { //,    SessionStatus status) { 
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
    // Errors, return to Form view
        return "messagePost";
    } else {
    // No errors make reservation 
        messageBoardService.postMessages(message);
    // Set complete, mark the handler's session processing as complete
    // Allowing for cleanup of session attributes.
    //status.setComplete();
    // Redirect to reservationSuccess URL, defined in ReservationSuccessController
        return "redirect:messageList";
    }
}
```

}

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.aaa.chapter5</groupId>
<artifactId>MessageBoard</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MessageBoard Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
 <glassfish.directory>C:/Tools/glassfish4/glassfish</glassfish.directory>
 </properties> 

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-alpha-2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


<context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/board-service.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>board</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>board</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

board-service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.aaa.chapter5" />  
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

board-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.aaa.chapter5.web"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

</bean>

</beans>

<bean id="messageBoard"
    class="com.aaa.chapter5.MessageBoardServiceImpl">
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Holy cow, that's a lot of code. I doubt you're going to get anyone to read through all of that. You're going to need to cut that down. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Sorry this is my first time to post. I was trying to show everything I have. I will cut down some. Thanks!

Comment: Just a sidenote: `listMessages` also should be synchronized (see *Java Concurrency in Practice*, *3.1.1. Stale Data*).

Comment: If you want to use only Spring (and not CDI) I don't think that you need `beans.xml` at all.

Comment: You really should decide if you want to use Spring OR CDI ... learning both at once and mixing their usage in one project is pretty advanced stuff (and maybe insane) ...

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is Spring code, since I could not get it to work. So I searched on internet and added @RequestScoped. But it gave the same errors. I did not have beans.xml.